# Rails capybara cookies issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cookies, capybara

How to work with cookies inside capybara?

in my `application_helper.rb` i have method with `cookies`

```
def user_currency(currency)
 cookies[:user_currency] = currency
end
```

but when i want to use this method in my test

it returns me

```
undefined local variable or method `cookies' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups
```

How to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Cookie manipulation is different for each Capybara driver.  The easiest solution is to use the [show_me_the_cookies](https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies) gem which provides a unified API.  Note that with some drivers you can only set cookies for domains you are currently visiting.